# winston logging http transport no port

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

I was wondering how I can use winston logging using the http transport, *without* any specified port?

I have a server and want to send all the error logs to it, but its just http://xx/api/v1/log

But in winston I weirdly enough cannot specify an empty port?

```
const logger = createLogger({
  level: "debug", 
  format: combine(
    colorize(),
    timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }),
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    logFormat
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.Http({
      level: "error",
      host: "xxx.herokuapp.com",
      port: undefined, // but this defaults to port 80
      path: "/api/v1/log",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
port: 443
```

More information [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#http-transport)